# Use protractor for desktop application testing

Tags: protractor

I have installed application on my desktop.I want to do the automation testing of this application with the use of protractor scripts.Please provide the suggestions.

Comment: Please add what you have done till now, this platform is not for spoon feeding.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of application you want to test. ProtractorJS is not the best tool for desktop app testing - since it designed for web-apps.

But if your desktop app built on electronjs - that changes the picture. In this case you can try to use this tutorial - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md

Protractor provides method `.wrapDriver()` http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Browser.wrapDriver 
So i think you can try to wrap that driver from tutorial into protractor instance and work with it. I never tried that, and unfortunately you should try by your own, since it is not a common use-case of protractor.

Comment: Initially this application was in webapp version and I have written the protractor scripts for the same.But now application got updated into desktop app version.is there any way by which I can reuse the already written scripts with the minimal efforts?